# How effective are modern aircraft at clearing smoke?

Tags: safety

In reference to [this incident](http://edition.cnn.com/2014/02/05/showbiz/justin-bieber-marijuana-flight/) by a certain (in)famous artist, i'm wondering **how effective modern aircraft are at clearing smoke** for single aisle commercial aircraft such as B737/A320 or a business jet like in the story?

- Which direction does the airflow in a cabin move? Top to bottom?
- How far are people effected by secondhand smoke if somebody lights a cigarette? Would it be within a one-meter range or would people notice across the whole cabin?

Comment: After those pilots donned their masks they should have depressurized the cabin LOL. It would have purged the smoke and shut that kid up real quick. Could wake him after the flight..

Comment: It seems like this would vary greatly depending on the aircraft in question.  What plane do you mean?

Comment: like a320? i would imagine there's a airflow requirement perhaps?

Comment: You may be asking about smoke in the cabin, but I thought of pointing a jet engine at a fire to blow the smoke away...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The most relevant data I could find was located [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9016748), in a study on "In-flight cabin smoke control". In the abstract, they stated that

> Tests on a Boeing 757, modified to allow smoke venting out through the top of the cabin, showed that the buoyant smoke front moved at 0.46m/s (1.5ft/sec) with and 0.27m/sec (0.9ft/sec) against, the axial ventilation airflow. Flight tests in a modified Boeing 727 showed that a ceiling level counterflow of about 0.55m/sec (1.8ft/sec) was required to arrest the forward movement of buoyant smoke. A design goal of 0.61m/s (2ft/sec) axial cabin flow would require a flow rate of 99m3/min (3500ft^3/min) in a furnished Boeing 757. The current maximum fresh air cabin ventilation flow is 78m^3/min (2756 ft^3/min).

In short, during *continuous generation* of smoke, cabin air will not be recirculated quickly enough to stop smoke from filling the cabin; however, if the smoke production is temporary, then it should dissipate quickly (time of course depends on the size of the cabin and the amount of smoke produced).

On page 2 of this [article](https://engineering.purdue.edu/~yanchen/paper/2007-3.pdf), a discussion of airflow occurs and contained this image, showing circulation patterns on wide-body airliners. A linked study on that same page noted that `an under-floor displacement air distribution system [like the commonly used type picture below] can provide a much better air quality than a mixing air distribution system`. The paper goes on to provide more diagrams of airflow and comparisons of various effectiveness if you're interested.

[image: Aircraft Circulation Patterns]

Boeing has a fairly detailed summary of their cabin airflow [here](http://www.boeing.com/boeing/commercial/cabinair/index.page). It says:

> Inside the cabin, the air flows in a generally circular patterns and exits through floor grilles on either side of the cabin and on airplanes with overhead recirculation, the air may exit through the overhead. The exiting air goes below the cabin floor into the lower lobe of the fuselage.

So at least on most Boeing planes, air exits at your feet, though it *can* exit at the ceiling. Airbus also has a page [here](http://www.airbus.com/innovation/well-being/inside/atmosphere/), but with much less detail. Airbus claims a complete recirculation every 2 to 3 minutes, while Boeing merely states airflow is continuous. The article linked below says in general, airplane recirculation occurs aproximately 20 circulations per hour.

An [NBC article](http://www.nbcnews.com/id/34708785/ns/travel-travel_tips/t/airplane-air-not-bad-you-think/) on cabin air states that to pick up a *sickness*, you need to be close, `usually within two rows`. The article goes on to say that:

> The aircraft is divided into ventilation segments of three to seven rows; you share air only with passengers in your segment.

So presumably if there were smoke, it would be captured in a small area were it not too pervasive.